# VS Code showing errors on template tag

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js

Please does anyone know how to resolve this error??

```
TypeScript intellisense is disabled on template. To enable, configure `"jsx": "preserve"` in the `"compilerOptions"` property of tsconfig or jsconfig. To disable this prompt instead, configure `"experimentalDisableTemplateSupport": true` in `"vueCompilerOptions"` property.volar
```

Answer (score 12):

in jsconfig.json

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "jsx": "preserve"
  }
}
```

write -->  "jsx": "preserve"

Answer (score 10):

You need to add `"jsx": "preserve"` to your config under the `compilerOptions` section. This is slightly different depending on how your project is set up.

This is the [officially recommended solution](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1219#issuecomment-1104548432).

If you're using a `.tsconfig` it will look like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve"
  }
}
```

With Nuxt 3 your `.tsconfig` will look closer to this:

```json
{
  // https://v3.nuxtjs.org/concepts/typescript
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve"
  }
}
```

If you're using a `.jsconfig` then it will be more like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

I wrote a short blog post on solving this here: [michaelnthiessen.com/typescript-intellisense-error](https://michaelnthiessen.com/typescript-intellisense-error)

Answer (score 6):

On file **jsconfig.json**

add:

"vueCompilerOptions": {
"experimentalDisableTemplateSupport": true
},

Answer (score 2):

**In your jsconfig.json, put the following**

[image: In your jsconfig.json, put the following]

**"jsx": "preserve"**

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error
write "jsx": "preserve" in jsconfig.json file did work.